# Java Arrays.sort(test) sorts two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have initiated an array in Java to be the same as another array. I have done this because I only want to sort a copy of the array not the original. This works fine the new array is filled with the original values. The problem then arises when I sort the array. The original also gets sorted. So my original is also sorted. How do I correct this so that only the copy of the array gets sorted.

```
double[] distancesSort = distances;
Arrays.sort(distancesSort);
```

Comment: Show us how you created a copy of this array.

Comment: show us the entire code.. are you doing something like                 double[] oldDistanceSort=distanceSort??.. i.e, how are you copying the array?.. valure by value or just by reference?

Comment: `double[] distancesSort = distances;` doesn't create a copy of your `distance` array. Use `Arrays#copyOf` method. Or just `distances.clone();`. It will work here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`=` is not used to copy elements of one array into another.

Use

`double[] distancesSort = Arrays.copyOf(distances,distances.length);`

`Arrays.copyOf(double[] arr, int length)`

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with zeros (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
>   are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
>   contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
>   but not the original, the copy will contain 0L. Such indices will
>   exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the
>   original array.

**Parameters:**

> arr - the array to be copied
>   length - the length of the copy to be
>   returned

**Returns:**

> a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros to obtain
>   the specified length

If you use `=` then `distancesSort` will refer to `distances`. Any changes in `distancesSort` will reflect the changes in `distances` also.